# Load multiple images with Glide on Android

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I want to make a simple gallery app on Android (like Google Photo or any standard gallery app). I've read that the best way to load images is use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library (Google recommends to use it). But how can I load multiple images (from sdcard) using Glide? I can use Glide.with(ctx).load(File file)... for loading single image, but I dont know how to load multiple. And what library does Google Photo uses (it works really great both with local and with cloud images)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the only one way to load images with Glide is to load them one by one using `Glide.with(ctx).load(File file)...`
But it's not a problem to use it even if we have a lot of images - it works perfectly. And it seems that Google Photo app for Android uses Glide, that's why Google recommend using it.